# Why does mod_security require an ACCEPT HTTP header field?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, mod-security

After some debugging, I found that the core ruleset of mod_security blocks requests that don't have the (optional!) ACCEPT header field.

This is what I find in the logs:

> ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx ^OPTIONS$" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsecurity/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "41"] [id "960015"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER"] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "T4F5@H8AAQEAAFU6aPEAAAAL"]
>   ModSecurity: Access denied with code 400 (phase 2). Match of "rx ^OPTIONS$" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsecurity/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "41"] [id "960015"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER"] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "T4F5@H8AAQEAAFU6aPEAAAAL"]

Why is this header required? I understand that "most" clients send these, but why is their absence considered a security threat?

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/issues/265

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't write these rules but as I understand it, there is a strong correlation between clients that don't include this header and malicious clients and also between clients that do include it and benign clients.

You may find certain bots (for example: Pingdom, HostTracker, UpDowner, magpie-crawler, Yandex, Yodao, MJ12, GigaBot and the LinkedInBot in a quick grep through my logs) that don't send this header however if you combine this with a rule that matches "normal" User-Agents such as Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera, etc. then you will be able to avoid blocking those bots.

There are some clients (or possibly a proxy that modifies the headers) that send an `accept:` header (and most other headers in lower case).  I haven't yet been able to determine whether these are malicious or not, however they all claim to be "Firefox/3.6.8" and have:

```
Via:HTTP/1.1 silk
X-Forwarded-For:10.161.106.98
```

or some other 10.x.x.x IP address in their headers... which is suspicious.

Answer (score 3):

RFC 2616 states that the Accept header SHOULD be present in all requests. Note that this isn't an absolute requirement, so a user-agent is still conditionally compliant (as defined in the RFC) if it doesn't send this header.

The rationale for denying requests without an Accept header is that all regular web browsers do send the header, while many bots do not. In practice, though, after seeing millions of requests, some "good" bots don't send the Accept header either. So this rule is not perfect and does generate false positives.

Comment: Where does 2616 say this? I don't see it anywhere there or in 7231 (which obsoletes the applicable parts of 2616).

Comment: The HTTP/1.1 Accept request header is specified in RFC 2616, section 14.1.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. My question was where this SHOULD is -- it's not there, or in the corresponding part of 7231.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's not an obligation,

This is justified, but not required by RFC2616 Sec14.1:

If an Accept header field is present, and if the server cannot send a response which is acceptable according to the combined Accept field value, then the server SHOULD send a 406 (not acceptable) response.

Although this is not required but it is unlikely that the user doesn't accept any content-types (otherwise, why would they bother to send the request?)

Comment: I see the "SHOULD" in section 14.43 User-Agent at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.43